# Save information to MongoDB database from form?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I want to save the information captured from an html form in a MongoDB database, I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Intro to Node and MongoDB</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <h1>Into to Node and MongoDB</h1>
 <form method="post" action="/addname">
 <label>Enter Your Name</label><br>
 <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name..." required>
 <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name..." required>
 <input type="submit" value="Add Name">
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

And the following javascript code would be my app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3000;

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


var mongoose = require("mongoose");
/*
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/node-demo");
*/

var promise = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/node-demo', {
  useMongoClient: true,
  /* other options */
});


var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 firstName: String,
 lastName: String
});

var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);

app.use("/", (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});



app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
 var myData = new User(req.body);
 myData.save()
 .then(item => {
 res.send("item saved to database");
 })
 .catch(err => {
 res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
 });
});



app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});
```

Apparently the post request is working, filling in the fields and pressing the input type submit, however when checking the database is empty, just as it was when it was created. Does anyone know why I do not save the information?

Comment: A few suggestions: 1. try logging `req.body` and `myData` to the console, see if it's they are what you expect them to be. 2. are you getting a reply from the server? 3. if you do, which one, "item saved to database" or "unable to save to database"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run your code here and the `app.post` was not called. It's because you're using `app.use` to send the `index.html`. `app.use` is used to bind [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) to your application. Instead, you should use `app.get`, which tells express to listen for requests to `/` and run the function when it sees one.

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```